# Compile Error: Block If Without End If

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to swap between 3 sheets every 6 seconds, it worked with 2 sheets when I added the sheet titled Dash I get a compile error Block if without end if

```
Sub Swap_Sheets()
    Dim dTime As Date

    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:6")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets"

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Plant View" Then
        Sheets("Dash").Activate
    Else
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "Dash" Then
            Sheets("Target").Activate
        Else
            Sheets("Plant View").Activate
        End If
        If gciConsole.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
            Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets", , False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Block If without End If` is a very straight-forward error, it literally tells you what is wrong, you are missing an `End If`

Comment: Using proper indent formatting would help you find where your error lies, and is good practice for many reasons.

Comment: If you are able to indent your code, it would help to see that your `if` & `end if` lines do not match

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the space between `Else` and `If` so:

```
Sub Swap_Sheets()

Dim dTime As Date

dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:6")
Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets"

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Plant View" Then
    Sheets("Dash").Activate
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Dash" Then '<~~~ Notice change here'
    Sheets("Target").Activate
Else
    Sheets("Plant View").Activate
End If

If gciConsole.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets", , False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like solution to OP's problem, +1 (not sure why someone downvoted..)

Comment: Did you mean `Else` and `If` ?

Comment: @MacroMan Sorry that was an error that I updated seconds after posting!

Comment: @Gareth I downvoted, because at first it looked like you were blaming the error on a typo which wasn't the case - but as you say you corrected it, and so I retracted the downvote.

Comment: @Dan No worries, please consider accepting the answer if you're happy it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change the second statement to an `ElseIf`:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Plant View" Then
    Sheets("Dash").Activate
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Dash" Then
    Sheets("Target").Activate
Else
    Sheets("Plant View").Activate
End If
```

OR include an extra `End If` at the end:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Plant View" Then
    Sheets("Dash").Activate
Else
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Dash" Then
        Sheets("Target").Activate
    Else
        Sheets("Plant View").Activate
    End If
End If
```